# Putting business logic into extension methods

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, extension-methods

There is a *third party* type `Person`. It simply exposes the `Subscriptions` collection which is a list of mailing lists a person is subscribed to:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(int id)
    public IList<int> Subscriptions {get;set;}
}
```

(It's [mutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), there is no any validation, everybody can clean it up, but that is a third party API).

I need to put some kind of a subscription business logic and looking for a proper place for doing that (subscriptions might have some validation rules, they might be added or removed automatically according to some conditions etc.). I can see two options here:

**Option 1:**
That might be a new `Recipient` type in my solution with all the business logic encapsulated in the `Subscribe` and `Unsubscribe` methods:

```
public class Recipient
{
    public Recipient(Person person) { ... }
    public void SubscribeTo(int mailingListId) { ... }
    public void UnsubscribeFrom(int mailingListId) { ... }
}
```

**Option 2:**
The same thing but transformed into `PersonExtensions` class:

```
public static class PersonExtensions
{
    public static void SubscribeTo(this Person person, int mailingListId) { ... }
    public static void UnsubscribeFrom(this Person person, int mailingListId) { ... }
}
```

The static extension methods may prevent me from creating numerous `Recepient` instances, but do not look like a proper place for putting the BL. Any drawbacks in doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely prefer option 1, in my opinion.  Extension methods are not for dealing with business logic; that should always happen in a class.  I think you have it right by separating the concerns of your `Person` class with the concerns of a person who is a `Recipient`.  You're definitely on the right track with option 1, if you're considering [SOLID design principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

**S**ingle responsibility, IE a class should only have one responsibility (one "reason to change").  Not germane to your question about using extension methods in lieu of classes, but it serves to prove that you are on the right track by separating the person from the recipient.  If your recipient logic changes, you shouldn't have to modify every piece of code that uses person but doesn't care about recipient logic.

**O**pen/closed -- open for extension, closed for modification.  (Don't let the use of the word "extension" make you think extension methods.)  You should always be able to add extensions (sub-classes) of your (preferably-abstract) parent class.  Fundamental principles of object-oriented programming like polymorphism come into play here, and none if this is possible with option 2.

**L**iskov substitution dove-tails nicely with the open/closed principle because it allows you to replace classes in code which require an instance of your parent class with an instance of your new "extended" sub-class.

None of this is possible if you put all your logic in one static class with extension methods.

Comment: That is my perception as well, I just didn't find a good source describing that. Could you please explain a bit how does SOLID adhere to this?

Comment: Add testability

Comment: If I need to process big data (1M+), can it be an argument in favor of the static extension method?

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree with the selected answer. 
Business rules change very often and adding them right in the domain entity, tightly couples a volatile logic to a likely almost immutable object. What happens if tomorrow you need to add more rules or change them because of mutated business conditions?. Or what if the same rule applies differently to different geographical regions? You'll need to intervene on your objects again and again, adding or removing methods and providing with increased complexity, thus, and verbosity. This is a very likely situation in most industries nowadays. Moreover, those methods are likely to be public. So anyone can potentially use them in the wrong way, unless you build a complicated application logic around them.

The solution is to decouple business rules from domain objects, delegating a third object the responsibility of deciding how to combine them and how (and when) to apply them. This is where business rules engines come into the picture. They allow you to create classes which encapsulate business rules for any of your domain entities, add them to the rule repository and trigger them as needed (so you really must know what you're doing). Another advantage is you're keeping your domain entities light and simple, free from the verbosity and complexity of business logic.

The more advanced engines use complex algorithms (like rete one), are able to figure out by themselves (most of the times) the exact order in which rules should be applied and support dependency injection. I personally use NRules: it's an open source, enterprise-ready rule engine, fast and reliable, built on top of rete algorithm.

https://github.com/NRules/NRules

Give it a try and let me know ;)